# Python RC Car Ultrasonic sensor blocking fast remote commands

Tags: arduino-ultra-sonic

I've made a RC car and recently I just got a kit that has all the stuff I need to add collision warnings, the problem is, is that it blocks codes and it will go forward with a lot of lag from the controller. I tried adding a thread to it but it still blocks the code.

I couldn't format my code correctly for the site so heres a github link
https://github.com/OoDone/RcCarPython/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how many CPU cores are used on your Arduino, I could imagine that one and the same core executes both Python threads, so that the busy loops in the function `pulseIn` slow the main loop. You could try inserting e. g. a `sleep(0.001)` in the

```
    while(GPIO.input(pin) != level):
```

and

```
    while(GPIO.input(pin) == level):
```

loops.